# Why have smarty3 authors removed lots of underscores in function names

Tags: php, smarty

I'm looking at upgrading to smarty3, but lots and lots of functions have changed name.

```
assign_by_ref
```

has changed to

```
assignbyref
```

This function is used in hundreds of places, does anyone know if there was a method to this madness?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can read in the README-file distributed with each Smarty-Download:

> The Smarty 3 API has been refactored to a syntax geared for
>   consistency and modularity. The Smarty 2 API syntax is still
>   supported, but will throw a deprecation notice. You can disable the
>   notices, but it is highly recommended to adjust your syntax to Smarty
>   3, as the Smarty 2 syntax must run through an extra rerouting wrapper.

The change has been made back in 2010 between Beta and RC phase of Smarty3.

Answer (score 0):

Not by anymeans ideal, but its very easy to add

```
 assign_by_ref
```

to `sysplugins/smarty_internal_data.php` by making a copy of assignbyref

this avoids using the apparently quite slow smartyBC wrapper and seems to work fine.